# sending a json associative array to PHP using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to send the following data structure to the Server using Json:

```
{"1":{"9":["Foto","45", "39"],"24":["Video","34", "8"]}, 
 "2":{"45":["Camara","3", "40"],"7":["Video","96", "7"]}}
```

Using the push function like this:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
var key 

    $("table tr.data").each(function(i) {
            var row = [];

            key = i;

            row.push($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
            row.push($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
            row.push($(this).find('td').eq(3).text());

            b[key] = row;

        });

        a[id_valor] = b;
```

But I will like to create an associative Array like this:

Because I don't know how to split this data structure to get each value of the variable `Array a`.

For that reason I will like to create an associative Array where I can see which data is what and send it to the Server.

Comment: What do you have the variable `key` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if i got you right... but you have a table, containing table rows with the class data. you want to loop through those rows and create a json to send to the server ...

if that's the case - here we go:

```
var myTable = {}; //declare a table object
$(".data").each(function(index) { //loop through each .data row, passing the current row index into the function
    var tableRow = []; //create row array for current row

    $(this).find("td").each(function (){ // loop through every table cell
        tableRow.push($(this).text()); //add the content of the td to the tablerow
    });

    myTable[index] = tableRow;  //add the table row array to the table object with 'index' as key
});

var myString = JSON.stringify(myTable); //create JSON out of table object
```

see working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdke87k1/

i've included an 'output div' where i put in the resulting json.
as far as i can see it - it differs from yours, since the outer bracket is missing. but i guess this should help to get you started.

Comment: Yes thanks @errand I got it already, I public my next question, how to analize (read, split) the Content of this Array in PHP to create several querys, ect and send a answer back to the Client (jquery)